# Rasa does not reply to first message, no response

Tags: chatbot, rasa, rasa-x

Versions Info:
Rasa Version     : 2.1.2
Rasa SDK Version : 2.1.2
Rasa X Version   : 0.34.0
Python Version   : 3.7.9

Chatbot does not respond to the first message, and can only start the conversation when I send the second message. Any one can help?